# Looking for an open-source PHP e-commerce system that supports a number of features

Tags: php, open-source, paypal, e-commerce

I would like it to have the following features:

- Supports multiple languages
- Allows admin to define a discount
  period on a number of products
- Allows members to register, login,
  add products to shopping cart and buy
  them (probably all e-commerce system
  support this)
- Members can pay by paypal
- Having a contact us page (with a
  working contact form)
- Products can be searched by users
- On each product detail page, there is
  an "Email to your friend" function.

What are the PHP open-source e-commerce systems that you know of, supports all/most of the features mentioned above?

Many many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out OpenCart, features list here: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=feature/feature

It appears to support most of what you requested, and there will be [extensions](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension) for that of which it doesn't support by default.

To be completely honest with you, the open-source eCommerce solutions are virtually non-existent, or where they are, not very good. opencart is the best I've used so far, and quite surprisingly it's very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Magento  http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it would be used on a shared hosting web server, Magento is powerful but its performance may drop a lot if not on a dedicated server.